# Using UISearchBar without a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I'm looking through the TableSearch example code provided by Apple.  In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, depending on if an item is being searched or not, the table gets updated.  I was wondering if this type of functionality can be implemented without using a UITableView.  I'm tryign to copy that functionality with a horizontal display of cards.  Thinking out loud, assuming this is possible, I would

- have my horizontal display of cards have a delegate that can be called when something is typed in the search bar.
- would i subclass UISearchBar to add this delegate, so I could do
  something like `searchBar.myNewDelegate = horizontalDisplay;`

Answer (score 1):

No need to subclass, just make your controller conform to the UISearchBarDelegate protocol and you can implement all of the text did change methods to do what you want.
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate

Comment: That's nice for his specific example, but the question asked (and the reason other people, like me, come to this page) is: how to make a searchBar without an associated tableview?  In particular, I want my iOS7 searchBar to NOT pop-up a table of "No Results Found" as soon as I start typing.  Thanks!  :)